# What is the Play! stage/reload behavior?

Tags: bash, shell, playframework-2.0

If I run the command `play reload` what boolean does it return if the application is not running?

If I do a deploy shell script that looks like:

`play reload || nohup play start`

will it start Play! if the instance wasn't running? Or will it fail regardless?

Comment: `echo $?` after running it to see the exit value or see the documentation of the application.

Comment: Came back as zero...going to have an answer for this very soon thanks!

Comment: Zero usually means success. Some programs frustratingly always return zero. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start off I had a misconception about the `play reload` command. It is in fact a part of the sbt tool and not the Play! application itself.

`play reload` returns as zero, and like Dennis Williamson pointed out it means success.

What I was actually referring to was `play stage` which readies the application for production in cases like an autodeployment.

Now my final deployment script looks like this:

```
play compile
play stop || true

nohup play -DapplyEvolutions.default=true start
```

Notice my handy shortcut to applying evolutions?

I've confirmed this works just as well and I ended up not using the `play stage`.